# Javascript make function wait for another function before continuing

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, async-await

Hi I have this function that I have written.

**GetIndex method**

```
  getIndex(req: connreq){
  var found = false;
  var number =0;
  this.firereq.child(req.recipient).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.exists()) {
      console.log('Not exists');
      this.x = '0';
    }
  });

  }
```

And I call it, in this function.

**SendCommand method**

```
 async sendcommand(req: connreq, cmd: string) {
this.getIndex(req);
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.firereq
    .child(req.recipient)
    .child(this.x) .set({
      sender: req.sender,
      Command: cmd,
    })
    .then(() => {
      resolve({ success: true });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      resolve(err);
    });
    });
      return promise;


}
```

However it seems that the second function continues before the getIndex method has completed. I assume we can use awaits and promises to force the sendcommand function to wait for the Getindex to finish before proceeding to the rest of it's tasks. Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: The same way `sendcommand` is promisified, you can also promisify `getIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

Return a promise in the getIndex() method and execute the second in a then call back. So generally, the getIndex should be:

```
getIndex(req: connreq){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
    {
        var found = false;
        var number =0;
        this.firereq.child(req.recipient).once('value', 
        function(snapshot) {
           if (!snapshot.exists()) {
               console.log('Not exists');
               this.x = '0';
               reject('Not exists');
            }
            resolve('exists');
        });
     });
}
```

The above will trigger the catch block if not found and the then block if found so generally it should be:

```
this.getIndex(req)
.then(() => {
    this.firereq
    .child(req.recipient)
    .child(this.x) .set({
          sender: req.sender,
          Command: cmd,
    })
    .then(() => {
       resolve({ success: true });
     })
    .catch(err => {
       resolve(err);
    })
})
.catch(err => {
  resolve(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first function do the following:

```
 getIndex(req: connreq){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  let found = false;
  let number =0;
  this.firereq.child(req.recipient).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.exists()) {
       reject("not exists");
      console.log('Not exists');
      this.x = '0';
       }
    else{
       resolve(snapshot.val());
         }
      });
    });
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
 async sendcommand(req: connreq, cmd: string) {
this.getIndex(req).then((data)=>
  {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.firereq
    .child(req.recipient)
    .child(this.x) .set({
      sender: req.sender,
      Command: cmd,
    })
    .then(() => {
      resolve({ success: true });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      resolve(err);
    });
    });
    });
      return promise;


}
```

This way `getIndex()` will return a promise and everything insde `then()` will be executed after `getIndex()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Return `Promise` from `getIndex` and `await` it in `sendCommand` function

```
    getIndex(req: connreq){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var found = false;
      var number =0;
      this.firereq.child(req.recipient).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
          console.log('Not exists');
          this.x = '0';
        }
      });

      resolve();
      }
    });
```

and

```
    async sendcommand(req: connreq, cmd: string) {
        await this.getIndex();
        ....
    }
```